# Retrieving the data from database for google charts using PHP

Tags: php, google-visualization

I have return an php code which is used to connect my MYSQL database and get the data from DB. This data will be used in the google charts for generating a chart. 
But my problem was I was getting an errors **"Failed to load resource  file:///C:/wamp/www/jquery-1.6.2.min.js  "  and "Uncaught Error: Invalid JSON string:  "**
I know that they are many things available still  I could not able to understand my problem. means how to rectify it.

My data base is like

```
 id  Q1-ans q2-ans
   21   50     40
   23   40      60
```

My code follows here

```
    <html>
  <head>
      <title></title>      
  </head>  
    <?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
mysql_select_db("mobiledb", $con); 
// The Chart table contains two fields: weekly_task and percentage
// This example will display a pie chart. If you need other charts such as a Bar chart, you will need to modify the code a little to make it work with bar chart and other charts
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `Q1`, `Q2` FROM `table2` WHERE `id`=8710058770");


$rows = array();
//flag is not needed
$flag = true;
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(

    // Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles
    // Note that one column is in "string" format and another one is in "number" format as pie chart only required "numbers" for calculating percentage and string will be used for column title
     array('label' => 'id', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Q1', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Q2', 'type' => 'number')

);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $temp = array();
    // the following line will be used to slice the Pie chart
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['id']);

    // Values of each slice
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Q1']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Q2']); 
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
echo $jsonTable;
?>


    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {



      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable('<?=$jsonTable?>');

        var options = {
           title: 'My values',
          is3D: 'true',
          width: 800,
          height: 600
        };

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
    }

    </script>
   <body>      
    <!--Div that will hold the chart-->
    <div id="chart_div" ></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must change:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is the quotes in this line:

```
data.addRows('<?php $data ?>');
```

as they are taking what should be an array of arrays and turning it into a string.  Try removing the quotes:

```
data.addRows(<?php $data ?>);
```

and running the script again.  If that doesn't fix the problem, either post a link to the page or the generated javascript (open the page in a browser, copy the source code from there) so I can take a look.